# How do I author a playable DVD from an MKV file containing MPEG2 video, audio, subtitle and chapter streams?

Tags: mkv

I'm using MakeMKV to back up my DVD library to MKV files without re-encoding the video or audio streams (since space is cheap, and quality is top priority.)

I'd like to know if there's a tool available (Linux or Windows), or a procedure using a collection of tools, that would allow me to rebuild the folder structure for, or even burn directly, a DVD player-playable DVD from these MKV files. I don't want to have to re-encode the video or audio streams.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

DVD requires more than just the video and audio data streams.  It also needs all the menu and table of contents data to instruct the player on how to play the stream.  As long as the stream is in an appropriate format, there is no reason that a DVD authoring package should have to re-encode the video.  It just needs to take in the stream and rebuild the menu and table of contents information that is needed to tell the DVD player how to play it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This I know - I was asking for a tool or toolchain to do the appropriate authoring for me.

Comment: @snoopy91 - just about any dvd authoring software should handle it.  You don't give enough criteria to recommend one beyond that broad guideline.

Comment: You can't rebuild the menu and table of contents from an MKV that only has chapters for the main movie.  If you want to save the original menus and stuff, back up your DVDs to ISO images (or directories of .VOB files).  But you could have a tool that builds a trivial menu that just plays the movie.  Maybe even auto-build subtitle and audio stream selection menus, if you'd rather have that than cycling through audio and sub streams while the movie is playing.